# DoubleRenderError in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Getting AbstractController::DoubleRenderError on rendering success message. Can anyone tell what is the issue here.

```
def send_alert
if (params[:community_id].present? )
    community = Community.find(params[:community_id])
    users = User.all
        users.each do |user|
            inspector_alert = Alert.where("alert_time >= ?",(Time.now - 10.minutes)).where(user_id: user.id,community_id: community.id)
            if inspector_alert.count == 0
                send_sms_to_user(user, "Approching your #{community.name}")
                render json: {message: "Notification Sent Successfully!"}, status: 200
            else
                render json: { error:  "Notification sent recently, try after sometime"}, status: 403
            end
        end
elsif (params[:home_id].present? ) 
    users = User.all
    home = Home.find(params[:home_id])
    if home.community.is_home == true
        users.each do |user|
            inspector_alert = Alert.where("alert_time >= ?",(Time.now - 10.minutes)).where(user_id: user.id,home_id: home.id)
            if inspector_alert.count == 0
                send_sms_to_user(user, "Approching your home #{home.name}")
                render json: {message: "Notification Sent Successfully!"}, status: 200
            else
                render json: { error:  "Notification sent recently, try after sometime"}, status: 403
            end
        end
    end
end
```

end

Comment: if you have more than one user -- you try to call render for each one

Comment: I have more than one users. But what is wrong in my code in renering

Comment: You are calling `render json` inside the each (so, for each user), but you can't call `render` more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails, you are only permitted to call `render` once in a Controller method/action. Since the function boils down to

```rb
users = User.all
users.each do |user|
  render json: response
end
```

When `User.all` contains more than one user (most of the time), it will hit the `render` function more than once. You are only permitted to send one response to a request over the internet. You might consider scoping the `User.all` call, using `User.find/find_by`. If this isn't acceptable and you do want to do this for each and every User in the database, you could collect all their statuses into an array, and send that back as a list of messages or errors.

```rb
def send_alert
  messages = []
  errors = []
  if (params[:community_id].present? )
    community = Community.find(params[:community_id])
    users = User.all
    users.each do |user|
      inspector_alert = Alert.where("alert_time >= ?",(Time.now - 10.minutes)).where(user_id: user.id,community_id: community.id)
      if inspector_alert.count == 0
        send_sms_to_user(user, "Approching your #{community.name}")
        # add this message to the pile
        messages << "Notification Sent Successfully!"
      else
        # add this error to the pile
        errors << "Notification sent recently, try after sometime"
       end
     end
  elsif ...
  end
  if errors.size == 0
    # no errors, send all the messages to this endpoint
    render json: { message: messages ), status: 200
  else
    # any error, consider this a failure
    render json: { error: errors }, status: 403
  end
end
```

Obviously, how this is executed exactly is up to your needs.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that you rely on an `if/elsif` block. There is the potential that this is provided neither `:home_id` nor `:community_id` as a param. If this were to happen, what would it render? It would fall past both paths and render nothing. Consider having some kind of default `render` with an `else` at the end, so you don't end up returning nothing/generating an internal error.